# Where is Google maps embebbed "customize map" button?

Tags: html, google-maps

In older versions of google maps we could customized embebbed maps. But in the new google maps version I cant't find this option.

Does anyone knows how to customize the embebbed map?

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?geocode=FSKzbAIdorOX-ykJIXyUFkTCiTGGeAAEdFx2gg%3BFcr4bAIdufOW-ymFsQbfR1rCiTHuQnzASyOJyA&amp;saddr=Brooklyn,+NY,+USA&amp;daddr=Brooklyn+Heights,+Brooklyn,+NY,+USA&amp;dirflg=w&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.678183,-73.944161&amp;spn=0,0&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?geocode=FSKzbAIdorOX-ykJIXyUFkTCiTGGeAAEdFx2gg%3BFcr4bAIdufOW-ymFsQbfR1rCiTHuQnzASyOJyA&amp;saddr=Brooklyn,+NY,+USA&amp;daddr=Brooklyn+Heights,+Brooklyn,+NY,+USA&amp;dirflg=w&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.678183,-73.944161&amp;spn=0,0&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start They moved to the API I think.

Comment: @Aibrean thank you, Aibrean, but still looks like it also does not allow customization

Comment: What kind of "customization" are you looking for? Your question is vague.